# can't access array outside a function no matter what I do

Tags: javascript, arrays

This is the html part:

```
<form>
<input id="input" type="text"/>
<button id="button"> Add! </button>
</form>
<div class="list"></div>
```

The script is like this:

```
var input = document.getElementById("input"); // save the object
var button = document.getElementById("button");

var myArray = [];



button.onclick = function alerted (){
    myArray.unshift(input.value); // get the value
    return myArray;


};

alerted();
document.write(myArray);
```

The problem is myArray always stays the original empty array no matter what I do. I would like to be enlightened, thanks!

Comment: Please noete that while named function expressions are useful, they are [broken in IE](http://kangax.github.io/nfe/#jscript-bugs) and shouldn't be used.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the name of the variable you assigned the function to, in this case `button.onclick()` will do. A named function expression lets you use the name *inside* the body, but you must use the reference name, not the function's name to call it somewhere else.

```
button.onclick = function alerted() {
    myArray.unshift(input.value); // get the value
    return myArray;
};

button.onclick();
```

Think of it this way -- you're assigning a function object to a variable -- That function object may or may not have a name (anonymous). So if your function has a name you can display it like so:

```
button.onclick.name //=> alerted
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it is still not printing out the new array, not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

I include window.onload so that we can assume that input and button is not null

```
window.onload = function(){
 var input = document.getElementById("input"); // save the object
 var button = document.getElementById("button");

 var myArray = ["hello"];



 button.onclick = function(){
    myArray.unshift(input.value); // get the value
    document.write(myArray);
 };

}
```

Comment: but document.write(myArray) still gets the original empty array, not the new one consisting inputs from the form.

Comment: how about using myArray.push(input.value); ?

Answer (score 0):

The following:

```
button.onclick = function alerted (){
    myArray.unshift(input.value); // get the value
    return myArray;
};
```

Assigns a named function expression to the button's click handler. The function **should** only be availble by the name *alerted* from within the function. Unfortunately [IE is broken](http://kangax.github.io/nfe/#jscript-bugs) (actually jScript is broken) in this regard and makes it availble as a global variable.

You should probably use a function expression:

```
function alerted (){
    myArray.unshift(input.value); // get the value
    return myArray;
}

button.onclick = alerted;
```

Members will only be added to the array when the button is clicked, before then it will be empty. Initially the input has no value, so clicking the button (or calling the function) will only add empty strings.